# What was the Amazon like during Green Sahara?

Tags: paleoclimatology, amazon

It is said that the Amazon rainforest receives [up to half of its nutrients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_rainforest#History) via [mineral dust from the Sahara desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_dust). But a few thousand years ago, the [Sahara desert was much more fertile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolithic_Subpluvial), having a savannah-like environment.

Did this mean that the nutrient transfer to the Amazon did not take place during this time? If so, what did the Amazon look like?

Answer (score 18):

According to the article [Africa: Greening of the Sahara](http://www.mpimet.mpg.de/fileadmin/staff/claussenmartin/publications/claussen_al_africa-hotspot_igbp_02.pdf) (Claussen et al.), the 'Green Sahara, occurred during the [Holocene climatic optimum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene_climatic_optimum), occurring at the same time as the  "African Humid Period", also similar ages to the events mentioned in your 3rd link.  All occurring during the mid Holocene

At the same time in the Amazon region, according to the article [Responses of Amazonian ecosystems to climatic
and atmospheric carbon dioxide changes since the
last glacial maximum](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1693334/pdf/15212099.pdf) (Mayle et al. 2004), was

> reduced precipitation in the Early–Mid-Holocene (ca. 8000–3600 years ago) caused widespread,
>   frequent fires in seasonal southern Amazonia, causing increased abundance of drought-tolerant dry forest
>   taxa and savannahs in ecotonal areas.

Although, this effect was not uniform over the entire Amazonian Basin, the authors conclude from pollen, charcoal and other samples, that the Amazon Basin had far less precipitation (up to 40 less in places), which caused

> increased fires and consequently greater ecosystem
>   disturbance, which would be expected to have caused
>   structural as well as compositional changes to plant communities,
>   such as expansion of drought-tolerant lianas and
>   semi-deciduous taxa within forests and expansion of savannahs
>   at forest–savannah ecotones. Populations of coldadapted
>   species (e.g. Podocarpus) were largely eliminated
>   from the Amazon lowlands during this interval, and cloud
>   forests on the eastern flanks of the Bolivian Andes diminished
>   while open, grass-dominated ecosystems expanded.

Comment: What is "ecotonal"?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecotonal): **ecotone** *noun* : a transition area between two adjacent ecological communities
**ecotonal** *adjective*

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s43247-020-00071-w) is a brand new (January 2021) study from Nature.

It proposes that the Sahara has not been the main source of dust for the Amazon for the past 7,500 years of Holocene, but rather dust from North and South Africa, the Andes, and Southern South America.